# Does it make sense to load scripts concurrently in Java 8 Nashorn JavaScript engine

Tags: java, javascript, concurrency, java-8, nashorn

Does it make sense to load scripts concurrently in Java 8 Nashorn JavaScript engine for faster startup? Will it rize any problems even if scripts do not modify global variables? I didn't find any information in `javax.script.ScriptEngine` javadocs.

Moreover, can Nashorn itself load scripts in parallel when `engine.eval(...)` is called from multiple threads at the same time? Is it safe to do so? If it doesn't, the whole idea of adding parallelism to scripts loading process is doomed.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it to see how much of a difference it makes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a good practice to compile your script files (lazily or eagerly) as CompiledScript then eval them.

Here are example codes: https://github.com/xqbase/util/tree/master/src/main/java/com/xqbase/util/script

Nashorn is not thread safe, as well as many JS engines like v8. If global variables are thread safe, however, calling CompiledScript.eval() concurrently seems no problems.

See anther question [Java Scripting With Nashorn (JSR 223) & Pre-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752196)