# when NOT to use Pre compilation in scripting?

Tags: java, groovy, scripting, jsr223

I read about [Pre compilation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752196/java-scripting-with-nashorn-jsr-223-pre-compilation) and [when you must compile script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012904/how-to-pass-types-and-functions-to-a-jsr-223-script).

I wanted to know if there are any cases where Pre compilation a script will cause script to fail or result in a wrong behavior ? or Pre compilation is always the right way when running scripts?

Is there option that a script will failed pre compilation but will work without it?

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the groovy [disadvantages](https://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/groovy-18-and-20-at-gr8conf-europe-2012/112-Static_Compilation_disadvantages_But_you) for static compiling are mainly missing dynamic features/ dynamic method dispatch.

I found an [example](http://blog.freeside.co/2014/07/08/compilestatic-and-polymorphic-method-dispatch/) for dynamic method dispatch:

> ```
> class Categorizer {
>
>  void accept(String s) { println "String: '$s'" }
>  void accept(Number n) { println "Number: $n" }
>  void accept(Object o) { println "Object: $o" }
>
>  void accept(Object... objects) {
>     objects.each {
>       accept(it)
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> new Categorizer().accept(
>   "a",
>   "${'b'}",
>   1,
>   true,
>   ["c", "d", 2] as Object[]
> )
> ```